# sbt librarymanagement ResolveException Error downloading com.atlassian.jwt:jwt-core

Tags: sbt, jwt, silhouette

Get dependency error (play application with silhouette) after switching to a new development system.

sbt.version=1.3.3

in build.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

```
[error] Error downloading com.atlassian.jwt:jwt-api:2.0.5
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/robert/.ivy2/local/com.atlassian.jwt/jwt-api/2.0.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/atlassian/jwt/jwt-api/2.0.5/jwt-api-2.0.5.pom
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The artifact `com.atlassian.jwt:jwt-api:2.0.5` seems to be available only from Atlassian's repositories (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jwt/jwt-api/2.0.5).

Add the following resolver:

```
resolvers += "Atlassian's Maven Public Repository" at "https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/"
```

Comment: I've tried: resolvers += "Atlassian's Maven Public Repository" at "https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/"  and resolvers += Resolver.url("Atlassian Maven", new URL("https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/"))(Resolver.mavenStylePatterns) without success ... the only thing that works is copying the files to: ~/.ivy2/local/com.atlassian.jwt/jwt-core/2.0.5/*

Comment: sbt tries to resolve local, public, local-preloaded-ivy and local-preloaded. The public url is always https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/atlassian/jwt/jwt-core/2.0.1/jwt-core-2.0.5.pom. And there is no such file at this address. Adding an additional resolver does not change anything.  Tried this with sbt Versions: 0.13.18, 1.3.2 and 1.3.3, seems that the address https://repro1.maven.org/ is hard coded.

Comment: @RobertJo it works for me. You probably have some settings in your build which change the resolvers inadvertently. Show the output of `inspect resolvers`.

Comment: `[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.Resolver] = Vector()
[info] Description:
[info]  The user-defined additional resolvers for automatically managed dependencies.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  Global / resolvers
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Classpaths.baseGlobalDefaults) Defaults.scala:2181
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  externalResolvers
[info] Delegates:
[info]  resolvers
[info]  ThisBuild / resolvers
[info]  Global / resolvers
[info] Related:
[info]  Global / resolvers
[info]  tousrv / resolvers`

Comment: See, you actually have no additional resolvers defined - the `Vector` is empty. Maybe you only have the resolver defined for a single project of your multi-project build? You need to show us your project - or a minimal project that reproduces the problem.

Comment: you are right that's it (oh man) thanks a lot! `resolvers in ThisBuild  += "Atlassian's Maven Public Repository" at "https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/"` fixes it.